# Save a file and then open it using javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a file stored in my project directory. I make few changes to it and then save it using FileChooser saved dialog box. After Saving I want this file to be automatically opened in my system. 
I succeeded in saving the file but not getting how to open it automatically without the user choosing it from open dialog box.
The code for saving the file is written below.

```
String input = "";
            try {
                OutputStream outStream = null;
                ipFile = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("upgradeworkbench/Resources/IP_template.sh");
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setTitle("Save");
                byte[] buffer = null;

                buffer = new byte[ipFile.available()];
                ipFile.read(buffer);
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                fileChooser.setInitialFileName("IP_template");
                fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                        new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Development File", "*.sh")
                );
                fileChooser.setTitle("Save File");
                File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
                if (file != null) {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outStream.write(buffer);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        input += line + System.lineSeparator();
                    }
                    input = input.replace("LogPath=$logPath", "LogPath=");
                    input = input.replace("ProcFileName=$ProcFileName", "ProcFileName=");
                    input = input.replace("BinFileName=$BinFileName", "BinFileName=");
                    input = input.replace("ReportFileName=$RepFileName", "ReportFileName=");
                    input = input.replace("FormFileName=$FormFileName", "FormFileName=");
                    input = input.replace("custom entries to be made by java code here", "file created");
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                    writer.write(input);
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Please help me how can I open this file as soon as it is saved in the local drive.

P.S:  I don't want to use `fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage)` to open a dialog box and choose to open the file. I want it to open automatically.

Comment: Say if is a text file then it should open in notepad, if a .xls extension file then it should open in excel.

Comment: @James_D while saving the file, it saves it with some extension, So according to that extension it should open up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a JavaFX solution, use the `HostServices`:

```
// getHostServices() is an Application method. You may
// need to call this in your Application subclass and expose
// it to the rest of the application somehow, depending on your
// application structure:
HostServices hostServices = getHostServices() ; 
hostServices.showDocument(file.toURI().toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Java Desktop API

`Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(yourfilename));`

Comment: You create a new `File` object like this: `File file = new File("path to the file")` and then you exchange `yourfilename` in the code i posted previously with this newly created file. Here is the API, which I guess you didn't look at: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Comment: It works fine. Thanku..:) . Cant mark the answer right as it uses AWT and not javafx.